# How to hide particle effect (Circles) until .png that it animates is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, canvas, particles

I'm currently using a snippet I got from this [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonnyc/Ujz4P/5/) I found on google. It works really well with my project and I already have it live on my site.

However. I have a slower connection -- Although I'm not sure if that's why this occurs, but i see "Neon blue circles" floating around the screen displaying the "particle's" before it loads in the .PNG that is animated as a smoke effect.

**My question:** Is there anyway I can hide these circles? Or possible delay the effect until the .PNG is loaded?

I may be making this more complicated that it sounds. I'm not too great with JS but i can dabble a bit. Any help is much appreciated!

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jonnyc/Ujz4P/5/)**

```
#myCanvas{
    background:black;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove/comment out these lines:

```
    this.context.beginPath();
    this.context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    this.context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)";
    this.context.fill();
    this.context.closePath();
```

This essentially draws a single circle.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Limitlessisa/Ujz4P/6158/

1. Step Add **style="opacity:0"**

`<canvas id="myCanvas" style="opacity:0" width="400" height="400"></canvas>`

2. Step Add js line **$('#myCanvas').animate({opacity:1});**

`imageObj.onload = function() {
    particles.forEach(function(particle) {
            particle.setImage(imageObj);
    });
    $('#myCanvas').animate({opacity:1});
};`

> Alternative smoke effect:

[JS FIDDLE Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Limitlessisa/bLajem94/)